# Asp calendar with datasource repeats the label

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have an asp calendar linked to datasource and it fetches the count of number of times a date has repeated in the data table and display it on the calendar. but if there are 2 dates of the same month is on the mysql table then the labels appears twice and thrice if there are 3 dates and so on as shown in the image below.

[image]

The code for this is shown below

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            cal2.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
            FillLeaveplannerDataset();
        }
    }
    protected void FillLeaveplannerDataset()
    {
        cal2.VisibleDate = cal2.TodaysDate;
        DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(cal2.VisibleDate.Year, cal2.VisibleDate.Month, 1).AddDays(-6);
        DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(cal2.VisibleDate.Date.AddMonths(1).Year, cal2.VisibleDate.Date.AddMonths(1).Month, 1).AddDays(7);
        dsleaveplanner = GetCurrentMonthData(firstDate, lastDate);
    }
    protected DateTime GetFirstDayOfNextMonth()
    {
        int monthNumber, yearNumber;
        if (cal2.VisibleDate.Month == 12)
        {
            monthNumber = 1;
            yearNumber = cal2.VisibleDate.Year + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            monthNumber = cal2.VisibleDate.Month + 1;
            yearNumber = cal2.VisibleDate.Year;
        }
        DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(yearNumber, monthNumber, 1);
        return lastDate;
    }
    protected DataSet GetCurrentMonthData(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
    {
        DataSet dsMonth = new DataSet();
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=myid;Pwd=abc123;");
        string caldate = "Select date From approved Where date >= @firstDate And date <= @lastDate Group By date";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(caldate, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstDate", firstDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastDate", lastDate);
        MySqlDataAdapter mysqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        try
        {
            mysqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsMonth);
        }
        catch { }
        return dsMonth;
    }

    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime nextDate;
        if (dsleaveplanner != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dsleaveplanner.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                nextDate = (DateTime)dr["date"];
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=myid;Pwd=abc123;");
                string cntdate = "SELECT COUNT(date) FROM approved WHERE date = @date";
                string cntdate2 = "SELECT COUNT(date) FROM pending WHERE date = @date";
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(cntdate, conn);
                MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(cntdate2, conn);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
                conn.Open();
                string count = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                string count2 = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                var slot2 = Convert.ToInt32(count);
                Int32 slot3 = 10 - slot2;
                string slot4 = slot3.ToString();
                conn.Close();
                 if (nextDate == e.Day.Date)
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    Environment.NewLine.ToString();
                    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    e.Cell.Font.Size = 9;
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p></p>Slot available:"));
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(slot4));
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p></p>Pending:"));
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(count2));
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cell.Font.Size = 9;
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>Slot available: 10</p>"));
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p></p>Pending: 0"));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender,
    MonthChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime firstDate = e.NewDate.AddDays(-7);
        DateTime lastDate = e.NewDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(7);
        dsleaveplanner = GetCurrentMonthData(firstDate, lastDate);

    }
```

What I want is if there is no data for a date i want the default value Slot avalable: 10 and Pending: 0 to be displayed. And I want the slot available and pending to be displayed only once in each date. What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the c tag??

Comment: means if `14-08-2018` is available 3 times in database then 3 lables print for same date, right?

Comment: Also, if it was me, I wouldn't have separate tables for pending and approved.

Comment: @ershoaib no, if threee different dates are there then 3 labels print, but if there is one date 3 different times then only once the labels display with the right values

Comment: show me your `select command` or `stored procedure` for `dsleaveplanner`

Comment: Thats also on the code I added, please look at  "protected DataSet GetCurrentMonthData(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
    {
       
    }"

Comment: If you trying to select date by group then how it will be repeated 2 or 3 times, If query runs successfully then it will return only one date

Comment: instead of group can you use `distinct` so no repeated dates will be there

Comment: ok I'll try right away and if you don't mind could you try the same and add as answer? I'll vote it

Comment: Actually it runs as it should be but this repeating mess happens only if add the label in the else condition, if I take off the label in else condition it runs fine

Comment: did `distinct` solves your problem then i'll add then answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177991/discussion-between-prkash-and-ershoaib).

Comment: @Strawberry that's a necessity for my purpose and that's not the issue, even if I have only one table the problem is still there. When I add the label in else condition for a default value that's when it happens

Answer (score 0):

First of all create one sample class with your name

```
class Sample
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int SlotAvailable { get; set; }
    public int Pending { get; set; }
}
```

And create a `List<Sample>`

```
List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();
```

Then change your `foreach` like

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsleaveplanner.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    nextDate = (DateTime)dr["date"];
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=myid;Pwd=abc123;");
    string cntdate = "SELECT COUNT(date) FROM approved WHERE date = @date";
    string cntdate2 = "SELECT COUNT(date) FROM pending WHERE date = @date";
    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(cntdate, conn);
    MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(cntdate2, conn);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
    conn.Open();
    string count = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    string count2 = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    var slot2 = Convert.ToInt32(count);
    Int32 slot3 = 10 - slot2;
    string slot4 = slot3.ToString();
    conn.Close();

    samples.Add(new Sample { Date = nextDate, SlotAvailable = slot4, Pending = count2 });
}
```

And then simply check if the `e.Day.Date` is present in our date in `List<Sample>`s date like

```
 if (samples.Any(x => x.Date == e.Day.Date))
 {
     e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
     Environment.NewLine.ToString();
     e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     e.Cell.Font.Size = 9;
     e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p></p>Slot available:"));
     e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(samples.Where(x => x.Date == e.Day.Date).FirstOrDefault().SlotAvailable.ToString()));
     e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p></p>Pending:"));
     e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(samples.Where(x => x.Date == e.Day.Date).FirstOrDefault().Pending.ToString()));
 }
 else
 {
     e.Cell.Font.Size = 9;
     e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>Slot available: 10</p>"));
     e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p></p>Pending: 0"));
 }
```

**Output:**

[image]